# Converting 25-May-16 into 'dd MMMM yyyy' format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs application.
There is a variable which is assigned a date value. This value is being pulled from a web API. This variable evaluates to '25-May-15'

Following is my existing code

```
//code to assign value (25-May-16 in this case) into $scope.models.AppointmentDate from Web API
....
var DateVal = $scope.models.AppointmentDate;
DateVal = $filter('date')(DateVal , 'dd MMMM yyyy');
```

This code gives me 'Invalid Date' value in DateVal variable.
What will be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the value of DateVal before you pass it into the filter?

Comment: DateVal has "25-May-16"  in it

Comment: That's not a valid date string

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have a date object, but probably just a string. Try something like this:

```
// convert to date object
$scope.models.AppointmentDate = new Date($scope.models.AppointmentDate);

var DateVal = $scope.models.AppointmentDate;
DateVal = $filter('date')(DateVal , 'dd MMMM yyyy');
```

Comment: $scope.models.AppointmentDate = new Date($scope.models.AppointmentDate); gives Invalid Date in $scope.models.AppointmentDate

Answer (score 0):

you should try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

you may use it like

```
moment("25-may-16","dd-MMM-yy").format("dd MMMM yy");
```

try it with your code and logic. Moment is also available for angularJS. explore more.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing date string to date object needs a lot of consideration. For instance: `new Date('25-May-16')` may work in newer browsers, but not on older versions. It may or may not work for your situation. I highly recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) because it takes most of these headaches away, but if you want a native JavaScript solution, use the following code snippet:

```
var DateVal = new Date($scope.models.AppointmentDate);
DateVal = $filter('date')(DateVal , 'dd MMMM yyyy');
```

You were trying to pass a date string into Angular's filter, which expects a date object as an input argument.

**Update:** MomentJS solution:

```
var DateVal = moment('25-May-16', 'DD-MMM-YY').toDate()
DateVal = $filter('date')(DateVal , 'dd MMMM yyyy');
```

It's important to pass the date format as a second argument to moment(), else moment will fallback to native date parsing method

Comment: Using new Date($scope.models.AppointmentDate);gives 'Invalid Date' issue

Comment: I updated my answer. new Date() works differently on different browsers. To avoid these pains, most people use momentjs.

I hope the updated answer helps you figure out the invalid date issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below

```
 var date = '25-August-16';
 $scope.date = new Date(date);
 $scope.date = $scope.date.toLocaleDateString("en-au", {year: "numeric", month: "long",day: "numeric"}).replace(/\s/g,' ');
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RlatXtIcK4QdOVlyGdG6?p=preview